# How to get first span from bottom value locate any where in the above div on checkbox click

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="demo">here is multplie span inside may be many other tags but fetch latst span text/value</div>
<div id="testing"><input type="checkbox" id="demo_id">Click me</div>
```

Comment: can you please create a working example of your problem and share all relevant Code ? also please be more specific about what you want ( there is no span in your provided HTML code ) .also share what you have tried to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#demo span" ).first().html();
```

With this example you will take the first tag span into the tag with id = demo